# "group by" like command in R with min as aggregate function and multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, aggregate, data.table

I have a frame with many columns 
c1   c2  c3  c4 ... c30 d

I want to aggregate by and find all rows unique in c1..30 and then get the min(d) for that row. In sql this would be a group by c1, ..., c30.

d is of type date.

I have found some solutions here in stack but none seem to work for 1) so many columns 2) do a min instead of sum.

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer using the `data.table` package with some fake data:

```
library(data.table)

DT<-data.table(matrix(sample(1:2,3000,replace=TRUE),ncol=30))
DT2<-DT[sample(seq_len(nrow(DT)),9000,replace=TRUE)]
# EDIT: now "d" is a date.
DT2[,d:=as.POSIXct(origin = "1960-01-01",rnorm(nrow(DT2), sd = 1000))]
setnames(DT2,c(paste0("c",1:30),"d"))

## pick up herewith your own data, starting with the commented next line
# DT2 <- as.data.table(dataset)
setkeyv(DT2,paste0("c",1:30))

DT3<-DT2[,list(minD=min(d)),by=key(DT2)]

dim(DT2)
# [1] 9000   31
dim(DT3)
# [1] 100  31
```

**Small addition from Matthew :**

+10, and nice fake data. Setting a key first so you can do `by=key(DT)` can get a bit onerous sometimes, so I'd usually just do an ad hoc by for something like this for simplicity. But, trying the most natural thing first :

```
DT2[,min(d),by=paste0("c",1:30)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT2, , min(d), by = paste0("c", 1:30)) : 
    'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=
    list(...) if you can. Otherwise, by=eval(paste0("c", 1:30)) should work.
    This is for efficiency so data.table can detect which columns are needed.
```

The error message tells us what we need to do instead :

```
ans = DT2[,min(d),by=eval(paste0("c",1:30))]
dim(ans)
[1] 100  31
```

The natural next thought is of course: well, if data.table is clever enough to know `by` is column names and put that in the error message, why can't it just do it?  The answer is that it's only making a guess based on the data. In some edge cases it's not so clear. So currently extra intent is needed from user: wrapping with `eval`. I'm not completely happy with that though, so perhaps we can improve that.

**EDIT: renaming the new data.table**

In my approach, I named the new column `minD` when I created it by entering

```
DT3<-DT2[,list(minD=min(d)),by=key(DT2)]
```

Using Matthew Dowle's approach, you would achieve this pretty much the same way by entering

```
ans = DT2[,list(minD=min(d)),by=eval(paste0("c",1:30))]
```

If you've already created the column and want to rename it, use `setnames` as follows:

```
setnames(DT3,old="minD",new="theNewMinD")
```

This avoids copying the whole `data.table` and preserves the memory over allocation (both of these advantages are lost when using `names(DT3)<-"something"`), as outlined in the documentation under `?setnames`

Comment: This was great, the only extra question I would have, is to how rename the new min(d) column. it gets named V2. Maybe data.tables work different, since i've tried the usual names(DT2[,c("v2")]) <- "new_name" and it does not work

Comment: @Jorchi, thanks for the question. `data.tables` do in fact allow you to work differently, including when renaming columns. Please see the edit at the end of the answer above for how to do this.

Comment: @Jorchi The usual `names(DT2[,c("v2")]) <- "new_name"` should work fine. Looks like you may have typed `v2` instead of `V2`?  Although the usual syntax works, it'll be as slow as base. As Ben says, `data.table` _allows_ you to work differently but does not _require_ you to. Otherwise we would have incompatibility problems with thousands of packages, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Untested without a minimal reproducible example:

```
apply(unique(dataset), 1, min)
```

Break it down:

```
x <- unique(dataset)  #finds only unique rows
apply(x, 1, min) # applies min across rows
                 # replace the 1 with a 2 and it applies across columns
```

Comment: Based on the SQL example, it seems the OP wants something of the `tapply` `aggregate` `by` ilk. That contradicts part of what he wrote, though, so I'm really not sure...